# loss decrease starts from second epoch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am using Python with Keras and Tensorflow (gpu).

I train a ConvNet for an image classification task. When I train the Network, I get following results for the loss function on training data:

**before** first epoch: 1.099

after first epoch: 1.094

after second epoch: 0.899

after third epoch: 0.713

after fourth epoch: 0.620722375

after fifth epoch: 0.532505135

Why does the decrease of loss function starts at second epoch? Why is there no decrease after first epoch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.094 is smaller than 1.099, so there is a decrease. What do you mean?

Comment: It's just started to look around for some minima, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras calculates the loss on training data while it is training. So, for the first epoch, samples in start perform way poor (because the model is not trained yet) and as the training progresses, model actually becomes better but due to poor loss on starting samples, overall loss looks poor.

On a side note, you can check `validation loss` which is calculated after the epoch and that'll be much better indicator of the true loss.

Answer (score 0):

The loss is decreasing but it's hard to say without looking at the variables why it barely decreased in the first epoch and it decreased more later. Probably the model took a while to find the way to minimize the function and in the second epoch the optimizer could minimize the loss function better.

Answer (score 0):

That is one confusing bit that tends to get ignored, because it usually does not have a notable impact. A typical training loop may look something like this

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Build graph
# ...
loss = ...
train_op = ...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while keep_training:
        _, current_loss = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={...})
        # ...
```

The thing is, when you call `sess.run` there, the `loss` value that you get is computed **before updating the weights**. `loss` is the value that is used to optimize the model, so it is computed and *then* back-propagated to compute the updates to the weights applied by *train_op*, so it cannot possibly use the new weights, as it is needed to get compute those in the first place! You could add another loss operation to the graph that is evaluated after `train_op`, but that would require evaluating each batch twice, and anyway you will see the new loss value in the next iteration. As I said, most times this is not important, but for example if you want to find out at what exact point some weights became `NaN` or something like that it can be misleading.